# how to identify the type of files having no extension?

Tags: c++, python, c

To do a work i want to identify the type of file. But the files are without extension.The files may be txt,jpeg,mp3,pdf etc. Using c or c++ or python how can i check whether it is a jpeg or pdf or mp3 file?

Comment: Read the start of the file, searching for headers which mark it as jpeg, mp3 or pdf.  For .txt files things are slightly more awkward; the best you can do is check for a byte order marker or a series of printable characters.

Comment: See `man 4 magic` for inspiration and for pointers to its database.

Comment: Extensions are unreliable anyway...

Answer (score 4):

Use **[libmagic](http://www.darwinsys.com/file/)**, a library for identifying file types based on various heuristics, such as magic headers (the first few bytes *usually*).

This is essentially what the well-known unix command `file` does use for identification. The good thing is: it comes with *predefined patterns*, so you don't have to reinvent the wheel yourself!

There exists a python module `python-magic`. Guess what it does. And well, for C, use `libmagic`.

See also:

[How to identify the file type of a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3470018/how-to-identify-the-file-type-of-a-file)

[Identifying the type of a file without extension from binary data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12190128/identifying-the-type-of-a-file-without-extension-from-binary-data)

Answer (score 0):

Some files, such as .exe, .jpg, .mp3, contain a header (first few bytes of the file).  You can inspect the header and infer the file type from that.

Of course, some files, such as raw text, depending on their encoding, may have no header at all.